# Embedded Widget on timer

Tags: flutter

I have a page which is a StatelessWidget and includes a widget to display the time on a page.  This widget updates at a periodic rate using the following timer.

```
timer = Timer.periodic( Duration(milliseconds: 541), (Timer t) => handleTimer());
```

When the timer pops, handleTimer updates the widget to display the new time.

I am seeing that the for every timer tick, the whole page rebuilds.  I was expecting that only the time display widget would update.

Is there any way to have just the time display widget build and not the whole page?

Thanks,

Comment: Could you share some more code where the widget is located and where you update it?

Comment: What do you mean by "the whole page update"? Do you mean rebuilding or paint? Because one can happen without the other

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to solve this issue, here are two:

1. The simplest is to create a stateful widget that just contains the part you want to update (the clock) and run setState in your handleTimer 
   `setState(() => digitString = timerValue);`
   Only the stateful widget will be updated.
2. Use a RxDart Stream. Create a Behaviorsubject and add updates in your handletimer method. Use the Streambuilder widget to draw your timer.

Comment: Actually, this is what I did.  On another forum, others are telling me that I should use the Provider / Consumer paradigm and only the Timer widget will be updated.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/flutter-dev/kbH07WykWpU

Comment: @philmagnuson Provider with changenotifier is just another way of handling state management. If you don't plan on incorporating it in other aspects of the app it's bloat. Both versions should do the trick, the version two with rxdart will only rebuild the part in its builder function, you can easily check that with a debug point. 
That said, I use provider with changenotifier in nearly all of my flutter apps.